# How to find mid of two locations on route in google map in android?

Tags: android, google-api

I am new to Stackoverflow, i want to get mid location on route between two or more location on google map in android.Can anyone help me with a example or some code?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this API
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Waypoints

In response you will get different waypoints try to use these waypoints to calculate center

Comment: Thanks for help, I will try it